# Going from webpage to website

Tags: html, css, web

I have been coding html/css for some time now, and I've gotten to be proficient at coding single webpages, but I can't figure out how to code a website. Some questions I have are:
Do I need to buy a domain if I want to build a website (for practice)
Are their special things I need to know (such as special tags) that I wouldn't have learned from coding just a single page?
Should I learn how to use a grid if I am coding multiple pages?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to first decide what kind of back end you want (the server side code that builds and delivers the pages)  I strongly recommend rails, and a [react.rb](http://reactrb.org).

You do not need a domain name.

A great way to start is to use a service like cloud9 which is free, and will get you going in no time.  Cloud9 will do a one button setup of a rails environment and get you going.

Another approach is to begin using react.rb and just expand your skill set from the front end towards the server.  The [react.rb tutorial](http://reactrb.org/docs/tutorial.html) creates a simple chat application  and you can do this all with the tools your already have.  Once you have mastered that you can set up a simple rails server and start adding server side persistance (saving data on the server.)  This is the approach I recommend, but full discloure:  I am one of the leads on the react.rb project so I am very biased.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can build simple to wonderful STATIC websites from HTML/CSS but if you are talking about some serious web development then you will need to learn a server side scripting language. Most of the websites these days are database driven serverside webpages. There are many serverside programming languages and tutorials for the same out there.

I suggest you start with PHP (for scripting language) and MySql (for database)
Again, the choice of language is totally upto you.

Then you would need to learn about setting up a server on your local computer. For this you will need to learn about (x)-AMP. This would be WAMP, XAMP, MAMP depending on what OS you are using.

If you are only needing to develop a simple CMS website, then there are alot of CMS framework which you can go for, which will not require much of coding.

Comment: You really don't need to learn about setting up a local server unless you really want to.  Start with a service like cloud9 that will give you a server, domain name, and prebuilt packages with everything you need.  To me learning to setup a server at this point just adds frustration.  But maybe that's me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you are looking to connect multiple pages to the same website, so you can navigate between pages. And it seems that you want to practice with local files. If that is the case, you need to first create a local folder for your website and use the *a* tag in your html files. Inside the *a* tag, you will need to include an *href* with the url to your other page. A link to another html page that is saved **in the same folder** as your original will look like this:

```
<a href="newPage.html">New Page</a>
```

You will want to use external CSS and JavaScript files to keep all of your pages in the same format.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp